# Geometry Nodes: How can I align points/instances to normals without local rotation?

Tags: node-editor, geometry, geometry-nodes

The lower torus is using a hair emitter and displays exactly what I'm going for: each instance edge is parallel to the next. The upper torus is using geo nodes and each instance has a local rotation. I've searched and experimented, but cannot figure out how to achieve the same effect with geo nodes.

The Point Distribute node provides the desired rotation/alignment, but the points are random so that doesn't work. Unfortunately, that's the closest I've come to a solutions thus far. I'm sure there's a relatively simple solution, but I'm struggling to find it.

Thanks in advance for any help <3

[image]

Here's a link to my file: [image]

Comment: Looks cool, I would say you need to reference the torus’s overall orientation. If each hexagon is in a “locked track“ constraint equivalent to the Z axis, it might work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was about to get buried in cross-products.. but a 2-stage alignment seems to do the trick?

[image]

Comment: That absolutely does the trick! I was on the right track a couple times, but I don't think I tried using two Align Rotation to Vector nodes. Thank you so much!

Comment: Robin is just a genius....!