# How do I correct the rotation of an instance for each face using Geometry Nodes Blender 3.0?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am using a normal value to rotate a simple cone instance along the parent geometry normals. It works great, but it appears to have a slight angle delta for each face.

Is there a way to "correct" the rotation of each instance?

[image: screenshot of cone instance]

Here is a screenshot of my Geometry Node structure:
[image]

[image]

Comment: is there a specific reason why you don't provide your blend file?

Comment: @Chris I updated the post with the blend file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to rotate individual points is to assign a `Transform` node to the instance mesh. In addition, the `Align Euler to Vector` node must be set to the `X` or `Y` axis in order to produce the intended results. Since the 4-sided cone appears diagonal, the xyz coordinates will be (90, 45, 90) on the `X` axis. For `Object Info` nodes, the xyz coordinates will be (0, 90, 0) on the `X` axis.

Result:

[image: geometry node face points]

Geometry node:

[image]

If you prefer to use the point normals, here is the more simple solution:

[image]

Comment: Very handy... where do these angles come from? The code, or experimentation?

Comment: @RobinBetts the coordinates come from tons of Youtube videos about Euler rotations and tons of experimentation lol. Feel free to upvote my question and answer if you feel this will help others.

Comment: I have +1ed, already :) I've been using 2 _Align Euler_ nodes, as [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/230782/35559) in the old-style. Just wondered if yours was a better way.

Comment: @RobinBetts my solution seems to act slightly off when applied to a Torus mesh. In Blender 3.0, the Align Rotation to Vector node doesn't seem to want to connect to the geometry point instance, but I'll message you if I figure it out.